# why there is pollFirst method in Dqueue?

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

`Dqueue` interface extends `queue` interface, the `queue` has a `poll()` method which does the same as what `poll first` in dequeue does, why this is required?

Comment: It's a convenience method so you can be explicit about which end of the queue you intend to poll.

Answer (score 1):

Because a Deque is a double ended queue, you can poll from both sides. In order to avoid ambiguity, one end is considered the first, and the other one the end.

A Deque supports `poll` so that it can be used in places where the declared type is a `Queue`. In a Deque, `poll` and `pollFirst` are equivalent.

In order to provide the double ended part of a Deque, one has to be able to access the other end of it by using `pollLast`. I suppose that `pollFirst` was added, so that a method call is unambiguous and that the methods are named consistently.